# Transforming a field in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

I want to transform an entity field as it is received by Jersey. How do I do that?

I have this entity:

```
public class Book {
  @JsonProperty
  UUID id;

  @JsonProperty
  @Isbn // Custom annotation, keeps dashes
  String isbn;
}
```

Now, when I get an ISBN, my validation makes sure it's a valid ISBN. That's working fine. But after validation, an ISBN also contains dashes (`-`). Those characters are superfluous. I can sanitize the data after having received it using my own methods, but isn't there any standard way to automatically transform some fields, just like I created a custom annotation to automatically validate my ISBN?

Note, I insist on the field having the proper value: it's important for subsequent frameworks to manipulate the field directly with the sanitized value.

Comment: `public String getIsbn() { return IsbnSanitizer.sanitize(this.isbn); }`

Comment: @JBNizet Care to elaborate? From what I understand, you're telling me to create a *different* getter? Is this you telling me to be pragmatic? Because your approach doesn't suit me as my field `isbn` itself isn't sanitized. If that's what you're telling me, I prefer to manually sanitize after receiving the item, just like I wrote in my question.

Comment: Why do you care about the field? It should be private, and you should never access it directly.

Comment: @JBNizet Because other frameworks rely on the field, not especially me.

Comment: Ah, I see. It would be worth mentioning it in the question.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay, it's updated.

Comment: Put the logic in the setter. That's what will be called when the object is created. Or put it in a `@JsonCreator` constructor